# Gibt es irgendeine Unterschied zwischen indes und indem?

Tags: synonym

BITTE KORRIGIERT MICH ALLES

Ich habe indes und indem als Vokabeln gelernt aber die übersetzen beide nach "meanwhile" oder etwas. Also sind sie austauschbar?

Answer (score 1):

They can be used synonymous, but...

... they are only synonymous, if you use a very antiquated meaning of 'indem' and to some degree also of 'indes'. Usually '[indes(sen)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/indes#1)' is used to express opposites and '[indem](https://www.dwds.de/wb/indem)' starts a modal sentence

Comment: *Indes(sen)*  may be used to express opposites, but its primary meaning is  simultaneousness, so *meanwhile* usually is an appropriate translation. *Indem* ususally can be translated using *by* + gerund.